# Spark Streaming job fails exactly after 7 days on HD Insights with no error logs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

The only error logs we get is : 
 Application application_1575912755011_0035 failed 5 times due to ApplicationMaster for attempt appattempt_1575912755011_0035_000005 timed out. Failing the application.

**What are the causes of it ?**
**What is the resolution?**

Comment: Try checking for more logs under job tracker or spark history if using yarn as master for spark.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-troubleshoot-application-stops

If that doesn't help, you might try running your streaming jobs in Qubole using Quest (Spark Streaming with ease of use built in) or by running Spark Streaming as is: https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/data-engineering/quest/quest-intro.html

best,
minesh

Comment: Hi, i am running my spark streaming job with spark submit , the documnet above is for livy